# How to generate Options(CORS) with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, aws-api-gateway, swashbuckle

For a project we are working on we are generating an Swagger File automatically. However at this moment we are struggling with the CORS part.

We are using the Amazon API gateway import api functionality. To use this in combination with Swagger and CORS, we have to create an additional action (operation) in our source code which allows CORS(options)  for each api method (operation)! 
eg:

```
    [HttpOptions]
    [Route("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public IActionResult UserOptions()
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }
```

As you can see this makes the code a lot dirtier. this is a temporary fix, but we can not find another way. Is there any way to generate this in the swagger definition file automatically? Or how can we do this, Amazon API gateway required this (documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

Comment: What version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: @HelderSepu: we are using version 1.0.0 =>  "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drive api gateway through [x-amazon-apigateway-integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html) swagger extension.

Using Swashbuckle [document filter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters), you can generate a option operation on all your paths without corresponding action in your controller.

Here is a sample code that will generate an option operation for all paths in your swagger and add use swagger extensions to generate a mock in api gateway on these OPTION methods:

```
    public class AddCorsApiGatewayDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        private Operation BuildCorsOptionOperation()
        {
            var response = new Response
            {
                Description = "Successful operation",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, Header>
                {
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new Header(){Type="string",Description="URI that may access the resource" } },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new Header(){Type="string",Description="Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource" } },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new Header(){Type="string",Description="Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request." } },
                }
            };
            return new Operation
            {
                Consumes = new List<string> { "application/json" },
                Produces = new List<string> { "application/json" },
                Responses = new Dictionary<string, Response>{{"200",response}}
            };
        }

        private object BuildApiGatewayIntegrationExtension()
        {
            return new
            {
                responses = new
                {
                    @default = new
                    {
                        statusCode = "200",
                        responseParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "'POST,GET,OPTIONS'" },
                                { "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"},
                                { "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "'*'"}
                            }
                    },
                },
                passthroughBehavior = "when_no_match",
                requestTemplates = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "application/json", "{\"statusCode\": 200}" } },
                type = "mock"
            };
        }

        public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
            {
                var corsOptionOperation = BuildCorsOptionOperation();
                var awsApiGatewayExtension = BuildApiGatewayIntegrationExtension();
                corsOptionOperation.Extensions.Add("x-amazon-apigateway-integration", awsApiGatewayExtension);
                path.Value.Options = corsOptionOperation;
            }
        }
    }
```

Do not forget to register that filter in swashbuckle:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            c.DocumentFilter<AddCorsApiGatewayDocumentFilter>();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, however, in combination with Azure API management. I used asidis' code and modified it to suit my needs.

Obviously, i removed the AWS extension part and i used a newer version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package (5.5.1)

```
public class CorsDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private const string AcaOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    private const string AcaMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    private const string AcaHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

    private static OpenApiOperation BuildCorsOptionOperation(OpenApiOperation operation)
    {
        var response = new OpenApiResponse
        {
            Description = "Successful operation",
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiHeader>
            {
                { AcaOrigin, new OpenApiHeader {Description = "URI that may access the resource" } },
                { AcaMethods, new OpenApiHeader {Description = "Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource" } },
                { AcaHeaders, new OpenApiHeader {Description = "Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request." } },
            }
        };

        return new OpenApiOperation
        {
            Summary = "CORS Preflight request",

            // Path parameters are required for Azure APIM
            Parameters = operation.Parameters.Where(x => x.In == ParameterLocation.Path).ToList(),
            Tags = new List<OpenApiTag> { new OpenApiTag { Name = "CORS" } },
            Responses = new OpenApiResponses
            {
                { "200", response }
            },
        };
    }
    
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
            var operation = path.Value.Operations.Values.First();
            var corsOptionOperation = BuildCorsOptionOperation(operation);
            path.Value.Operations.Add(OperationType.Options, corsOptionOperation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues and I end up creating a utility in Java which automatically adds these headers to Swagger JSON. You can run it before importing it to API Gateway and import the output JSON which has CORS enabled in all the methods

https://github.com/anandlalvb/SwaggerToAPIGateway

It is tedious task to add these headers to all your methods in Swagger JSON.

```
            "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
```

I hope this utility may help you to do that easily

Answer (score 0):

Do the steps to 'Enable CORS' using the easy one-click feature in the console, then deploy the API, and finally go to the Stage and Export the API back to swagger.

Now you can inspect the swagger to see how to configure CORS in your own swagger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i want to create these options in an automated manner. In our project we are just delivering the swagger file to an AWS partner and they import it into API gateway.