# AWS API Gateway Swagger using swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I want to generate the AWS API Gateway swagger (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-as-lambda-proxy-export-swagger-with-extensions.html) from the ASP.NET Core web API using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

Please let me know if someone have solution for this.

NOTE: I came across this [How to generate Options(CORS) with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281325/how-to-generate-optionscors-with-swagger). and want to do the same thing. Could you please guide me on this?

Thanks,
Abidali

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS Api gateway uses x-amazon-apigateway-* extensions in swagger to configure your REST Api.

I don't think there is already a library that will manage it for you via Swashbuckle but Swashbuckle has some interfaces you can implement to generate custom swagger extensions as explained in [Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters). For example, if you want to generate the x-amazon-apigateway-integration extention you can do it by implementing `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter` interface:

```
    public class AwsApiGatewayIntegrationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            operation.Extensions.Add("x-amazon-apigateway-integration",new
            {
                type = "aws",
                uri = "arn_to_your_aws_resource"
            });
        }
    }
```

And configure it during swagger generator setup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "My API",
                Description = "",
                TermsOfService = "",
            });
    c.OperationFilter<AwsApiGatewayIntegrationFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @asidis. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

A more up to date version of asidis answer would look like: (using dotnet 3.0.0 and swashbuckle 5.0.0-rc4)

```
public class AwsApiGatewayIntegrationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Extensions.Add("x-amazon-apigateway-integration", new OpenApiObject
        {
            ["type"] = new OpenApiString("aws"),
            ["uri"] = new OpenApiString("uri_to_your_aws_resource"),
        });

    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
      c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
      c.OperationFilter<AwsApiGatewayIntegrationFilter>();
);
```